# Getting substring of a string that exists between patterns

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
$string = 'startTHISISTHESTRINGINEEDend'
```

I need the string between start and the end obviously. I tried regex but its way hard for a newbie like me so no succes on that side. The length of end part is changing so substr function is no go. Tried to combine `strpos` with `strstring` but no success on that too. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this; will provide a detailed explanation so the whole concept of the regex is simplified doesn’t seem like magic:

```
$string = "startTHISISTHESTRINGINEEDend";

preg_match("/^start([a-z0-9]+)end$/is", $string, $matches, null, 0);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

The regex is fairly simple. And here is the explanation.

- Match `start` at the beginning of the string; that is what the `^` means.
- Next the parentheses of `(` and `)` basically mean you are capturing what are in between the parentheses.
- So in between the `(` and `)` is regex logic to capture only alphanumeric characters as represented by `[a-z0-9]+`.
- Match `end` at the end of the string; that is what the `$` means.
- The `is` at the end of the the regex basically means make sure the match is case insensitive via the `i` (aka: `PCRE_CASELESS`) and then the `s` indicates a `PCRE_DOTALL` which as explained in the [PHP manual on pattern modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> If this modifier is set, **a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches
>   all characters, including newlines.** Without it, newlines are excluded.
>   This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class
>   such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the
>   setting of this modifier.

If you wish to include non alpha numeric characters you can just use this `(.*?)` instead of `([a-z0-9]+)`. But unclear from your request since you are only showing alphabet characters. Or if you wanted to capture specific non-alphanumeric characters like `%`, `/` & `^` then just do this: `([a-z0-9%\/^]+)`. Note how the `/` is set as `\/`. Adding the `\` escapes the `/` which makes `preg_match` realize that it needs to explicitly match `/` & not interpret that as part of the regex logic.

And the output of `$matches` would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => startTHISISTHESTRINGINEEDend
    [1] => THISISTHESTRINGINEED
)
```

So just access it by referring to `$matches[1]`.

```
echo $matches[1];
```

Output would be:

```
THISISTHESTRINGINEED
```

Comment: I'll remove my answer in favor of yours as you have a PHP specific solution. Could you just jot a quick edit down explaining what the `[a-z0-9]+` does for this poster's sake?

Comment: Holy cow.  I think you just answered 50% of all regex questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That's really a good explanation. Thanks a lot. But I didn't get the [a-z0-9]+ part. So characters like % / ^ will be ignored then?

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = str_replace("start","", $string);
$string = str_replace("end","", $string);
echo $string;
```

Not a wise solution but probably sufficient one

Answer (score 0):

```
start(.*?)end
```

then get Group#1. In [demo](http://regex101.com/r/lN1tE5) look at Group#1.

Answer (score 0):

If your `start` and `end` occurs somewhere in a string (only once) and you don't want to use regular expressions, you can use the following solution:

```
$string = 'HIstartTHISISTHESTRINGINEEDendANDOTHERSTUFFHERE';
$start = strpos($string, 'start') + strlen('start');
$end = strrpos($string, 'end');
$result = substr($string, $start, $end-$start);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'xwerwstartTHISISTHESTRINGINEEDasdwerendwerq';

$start = 'start';
$stop = 'end';

echo substr($string, 
    strlen($start) + strpos($string, $start), 
    strpos($string, $stop) - (strpos($string, $start) + strlen($start))
);
```